# How can I attach images to a post from the media library?

Tags: plugins, images, media-library

Currently, there is no way to do this in a vanilla Wordpress install. Is there a way to retroactively attach an image from the Library to a post?

EDIT: Ah, let me clarify — when editing a post, and clicking the "Insert Media" button, I see no way to add past media. I can insert it into the post, but not add it to the post gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that is currently supported in WordPress. There's some discussion about it here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6820

One plugin which does enable this functionality is:

http://skyphe.org/code/wordpress/file-gallery/

This plugin does a few extra things, but one option it provides is that after clicking "upload/insert" and going to the media library tab, you can tick check boxes beside images and choose to attach them to the current post.

There's also an old thread on WordPress support forums which pertains to adding a small bit of code to your functions.php file to enable this functionality but I think that only works within the Media Library section, not when in the Upload/Insert thickbox, so the above plugin might be your best bet.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/detach-amp-re-attach-media-attachment-images-from-posts?replies=21

Comment: Here's the official repository link for the File Gallery plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/file-gallery/

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a little glitch in Media panel, when attaching multiple files at once, do the following:

- Access Media Library panel
- Click the link **Unattached**
- Now you see only unattached files then select the files you want attach
- select **Attach** in **Bulk Actions** drop down and choose the page/post.

Right when accessing the panel, the Bulk Actions doen't shows the Attach option.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Not a normal thing, Some plugin or theme is doing this, you better deactivate plugins and try the default theme.

Comment: I can assure you that nothing is interfering with the Media Library — I can even send some screenshots.

Comment: I can insert them into the post, but not add them into the post gallery.

Comment: Ah I see, there's no way to attach a file to multiple posts. The gallery shortcode only display the files within the post. You can use a plugin such portfolio slideshow and inform (plugin shortcode) which images display. The WOrdPress shortcode is fro attached files of current post only.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you believe there's no way to attach an unattached item directly from the media library by default - in the list of media library items, You'll see a column for "Attached to". Items that are not attached to anything will say (Unattached) and then have a link to attach the item to a post.

Comment: Please see my edit.